# Open webview on top of a React Native App

Tags: react-native

I would like to open a link "in-app" without leaving a React Native app. The idea would be to open a webview on top of the application when clicking the link like Gmail or Messenger do.

Is there a way to do this in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create a new screen, with a rendered WebView inside.

You may refer to this link: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/webview/#__next

In your router, (if you're using react-navigation) you can just use "modal" for your navigation's mode.

Comment: Your link seems broken but I guess I have an idea now

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```